# Can't Set Values in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im new to Script Editor on google sheets and struggling a little.
Im having issues setting values when pulling from separate sheet(getbyid).

For example...

```
function myFunction() {
var todaysdate =  Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+10", "dd/MM")
var sheetname = ("Vote - " + todaysdate)
var spreadsheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('14LD0P2v89W6nM7JI-sU1FFkCZ0Pa-L6iVgZh0gPoPwQ')
var spreadsheet2 = spreadsheet1.getSheetByName(sheetname)
spreadsheet1.getRange("B3").setValue("TssEXsdT");
 }
```

This works on its own, but when I add it to my main code it doesn't work anymore?

Also, The following code returns the first line from the getRange in all the cells in the setValue.
ie
Brewers
Brewers
Brewers
Brewers
... etc

```
   var newresultspage = source.getSheetByName(resultsheetname);
   var beernamespage = source.getSheetByName('beer names')
   var brewers = beernamespage.getRange('d3:d9').getValues('d3:d9'); 
   newresultspage.getRange('j5:j11').setValue(brewers);
```

I don't understand how to get it to populate the list?

Any help would be amazing.
James

Comment: Can you please format your code for readability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `my main code` of `but when I add it to my main code it doesn't work anymore?` is the bottom script in your question, how about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- I think that in your script, an error occurs at `var brewers = beernamespage.getRange('d3:d9').getValues('d3:d9');` . Because `getValues` has no arguments. But in your question, you say `The following code returns the first line from the getRange in all the cells in the setValue. ie Brewers Brewers Brewers Brewers ... etc`. So I'm worry that your script might be different from the script for replicating your issue.
- When `var brewers = beernamespage.getRange('d3:d9').getValues('d3:d9');` is `var brewers = beernamespage.getRange('d3:d9').getValues();`, this line occurs no error and `brewers` has the value of 2 dimensional array.

  - In this case, at `newresultspage.getRange('j5:j11').setValue(brewers);`, the value of 1st element of the 1st array in `brewers` is put to the cells `j5:j11`. I think that the reason of your issue is due to this.
  - So please modify `setValue` to `setValues`.

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please modify as follows.

From:

```
var brewers = beernamespage.getRange('d3:d9').getValues('d3:d9');
newresultspage.getRange('j5:j11').setValue(brewers);
```

To:

```
var brewers = beernamespage.getRange('d3:d9').getValues();
newresultspage.getRange('j5:j11').setValues(brewers);
```

- Above modified script retrieves the values from "d3:d9" of `beernamespage` and put it to "j5:j11" of `newresultspage`.

#### Note:

- If `d3:d9` is changed while `j5:j11` is kept, an error might occur. At that time, it is required to be the same size of range with the retrieved values. Please be careful this.

  - In your current script, both `d3:d9` and `j5:j11` are 7 rows and 1 column. By this, above modified script works.

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: Thanks, This fixed the issue. Such a simple mistake.

Comment: @James Marchetti Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.